# HDInsight Azure Blob Storage Change

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

On HDInsight cluster, a Hive table is created using CREATE EXTERNAL statement:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE HTable(t1 string, t2 string, t3 string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'wasb://$containerName@$storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net/HTable/data/';
```

Then some existing files changed, some files are added to Azure Blob Container mentioned in the CREATE statement.

Does a new hive query consider changes made to Blob Container with out again loading data to hive table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your table definition is saved in the Hive metastore. You can subsequently simply query `HTable` and data will be there. Normally Hive on HDInsight follows the same rules that applies to Hive and HDFS.

For a more advanced discussion you *can* play some tricks, but you need to know what you're doing. Because HDInsight storage can survive a cluster lifetime, with HDInsight is feasible to tear down the cluster and redeploy  a *new* HDInsight cluster and still have the Hive data. You can even keep the Hive metastore, as is a separate database (an SQL Azure DB). With an HDFS based cluster a recycle of the cluster leads to loss of all HDFS data.

Comment: Thanks Remus, I haven't got chance to explore things on HDInsight Cluster but I need some info to come out with possible bigdata solution. I am afraid to consider HDInsight because of the changes to the existing data from external sources.

Comment: " am afraid to consider HDInsight because of the changes to the existing data from external sources" not sure I understand that. Can you explain?

Comment: upstream database is a trasactional db. when any data changes there, an azure worker role will capture that from service bus and change the corresponding file on the blob storage

Comment: Hive is not going to like blobs being updated behind its back, no matter the file system. I think you need to consider Hive partitioning.

Comment: how hive partitioning is going to help in this particular case? what i think is partitioning enables quick results on querying.

Comment: Partitioning allows you to upload new data into new partitions (new files). This way BLOBs are immutable.